# c++ null terminated array of objects

Tags: c++, arrays, null-terminated

I am trying to create a null terminated array of objects like this

```
void Game::createCreatures(int numCreatures) {
    creatures = new Creature *[numCreatures + 1];
    for (int i = 0; i <= numCreatures; i++) {
        if(i < numCreatures) {
            creatures[i] = new Runner(maze);
        } else creatures[i] = NULL;
    }
}
```

Then access them like this

```
for (Creature *creature = creatures[0]; creature != NULL; creature++) {
    creature->travel();
}
```

What exactly am I doing wrong? I am receiving a EXC_BAD_ACCESS when I attempt to 'travel' the creature. I know there is something wrong with the creation of the array because if I attempt to print the address of all of the creatures using my accessing for loop, it prints forever. I know there is something wrong with my pointer logic, help?

creatures declaration is this

```
Creature **creatures;
```

Comment: If this isn't an assignment, seriously, consider `std::vector` and `std::unique_ptr` :V.

Comment: @Sneftel that gives me the error 'invalid operands to binary expression Creature and long', dereferencing the pointer to a creature shouldn't give me a null ever (actually it is the pointer that should be null I believe so dereferencing will throw an error)

Comment: @MohammadAliBaydoun I am doing this for my own understanding and enjoyment, but thanks for the suggestion

Comment: @user3667450 - Isn't there enjoyment in creating a working program that has no bugs in a quick amount of time?

Comment: I see no point in discouraging someone from trying something even if that something is not the optimal way. That's how we learn after all.

Comment: Right, you're making my point.  Why not learn all the ways, including the optimal way?

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie you are right, but I still want to figure it out for myself. If I really wanted to build an optimal game like you say I would be doing it in python.

Comment: @user3667450 - If you want to see how to create the null terminated array using std::vector: `std::vector<Creature*> creatures(numCreatures, new Runner(maze));  creatures.push_back(0);`  The rest of your code basically stays the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The access loop should be:

```
for (int i = 0; creatures[i] != NULL; i++) {
    Creature *creature = creatures[i];
    creature->travel();
}
```

Your loop is treating `creatures[0]` as an array of creatures, but it's just a single creature.

If you want to do the loop with pointer arithmetic, it should be:

```
for (Creature **creature = &creatures[0]; *c != NULL; c++) {
    (*creature)->travel();
}
```

Comment: Wouldn't it be `for (Creature **creature = ...` then ?

Comment: Would it then make more sense to have Creature *creatures = new Creature[num], rather than creatures as Creature **creatures?

Comment: That won't work if you're making use of virtual inheritance, so the array can contain pointers to different subclasses of `Creature`. That seems to be what you're doing in `createCreatures`, you're setting them to `new Runner` instead of `new Creature`.

Comment: That doesn't work, because then the compiler complains that creature (in the for loop) cannot be set equal to creatures (aka a Creature* cannot be set equal to a Creature**) which is what &creatures[0] is

Comment: I think I got it wrong in the second block, it should be `Creature **creature`.

Answer (score 2):

Your `creature` is a pointer to a `Creature`.  If you increment this pointer, you will point to the next `Creature` behind the currently pointed one and not to the next pointer in your table.

Use:

```
for (int i=0; creatures[i]!=nullptr; i++) {
        creatures[i]->travel();
    }
```